# NumberOfSymbols is recognised in the For Loop range when the local variable line is # out. Why is it acting as a global?

Tags: python

```
def OutputSymbols():
    Symbol = '*'

    for i in range(0,NumberOfSymbols):
        print(Symbol,end='')    
    print()
    #NumberOfSymbols = NumberOfSymbols +1

NumberOfSymbols = 5  
OutputSymbols()
```

NumberOfSymbols is recognised in the For Loop range when the local variable line is # out. Why is it acting as a global? Taking away the # makes it act as a local variable. Why? This is the error message that appears when the line line  NumberOfSymbols = NumberOfSymbols +1 is # out.

```
for i in range(0,NumberOfSymbols):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'NumberOfSymbols' referenced before assignment
```

Would you please be able to correct this and explain why this is not working? Thanks

Comment: BTW, you might want to read the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment to `NumberOfSymbols` *anywhere* in the function makes it a local variable thoughout the scope, even seemingly "retroactively" on a previous line. Without such an assignment, it is not a local variable, but a free variable that can resolve in any enclosing non-local scope, including the global scope.

If you want to assign to a global variable, you need to use a `global` statement.

```
def OutputSymbols():
    global NumberOfSymbols
    Symbol = '*'

    for i in range(0,NumberOfSymbols):
        print(Symbol,end='')    
    print()
    NumberOfSymbols = NumberOfSymbols +1

NumberOfSymbols = 5  
OutputSymbols()
```

Comment: I hope you keep editing the question and explain why using `global` is a bad idea in >99.9% of all cases.

Comment: It's not entirely clear that even the OP wants to use a global variable, as nothing else in the code would seem to warrant incrementing that value.